# Quick USB pendrive formatting under KDE

Tags: kde, usb-drive, mkfs

Is there some way to quickly format a USB pendrive in KDE (with a GUI interface), without having to open the main "KDE Partition Manager"?

In particular I'm most interested in something like a Dolphin plugin or a Plasmoid.

If it matters, I'm on Kubuntu 12.04 with KDE 4.10.

Comment: most fastest way to do partition is from cfdisk or fdisk on terminal..

Comment: Thank you, I know about the CLI commands, but I'm looking for a GUI utility.

Comment: There are several tools in Ubuntu and the Ubuntu community flavours (Kubuntu et.al). You are running an old version, 12.04 LTS that has passed end of life. How updated is it? Are you still running the precise kernel series (12.04.1) or have you updated the hardware enablement stack and the trusty kernel (12.04.5)? It may make a difference concerning which tools will work well. Anyway, I have the (standard) Ubuntu `ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso` and `ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-i386.iso` files and can test with them what works, and it is likely to work also with the corresponding Kubuntu files...

Answer (score 1):

New answer for an old question.

---

[Mintstick from Linux Mint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/172476/32012) is the quickest, containing two separate gui tools, one to format an USB drive  ("USB Stick Formatter"), one to write an image on it ("USB Image Writer").

To install it in older Ubuntu

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tsvetko.tsvetkov/trusty-backports
```

or

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tsvetko.tsvetkov/xenial-backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mintstick
```

For **Ubuntu 18.04**, until a newer version is launched along with an Ubuntu 18.04-based Linux Mint, download latest version 1.3.8 from [here](https://pkgs.org/download/mintstick).

Open a terminal at the location of the download and do

```
sudo dpkg -i mintstick_1.3.8_all.deb
```

Install the missing dependencies.

If needed do

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

then do again  `sudo dpkg -i mintstick_1.3.8_all.deb`.

Run it by typing "USB Stick Formatter" in a launcher - or `mintstick -m format` in terminal.

[image]

---

In case that cannot be installed on your system, a good alternative is `gnome-multi-writer`. It is able to format a stick before writing, but *cannot simply format (without writing anything)*. For that, one can use "Disks" (gnome-disk-utility), which is a bit quicker than Gparted or the KDE Partition Manager.

If the usb stick already contains a live Linux, it is a bit trickier: first, select "Format Disk" from the top right corner (NOT "Format partition" ),

[image]

then select "Partitioning: No partitioning".

And only then select Additional partitioning options - "Format partition" , FAT, Next, Format.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can verify that **mkusb** works in 12.04.1 and 12.04.5 iso files and I think will also work in a corresponding installed Kubuntu system. It can not only

- **wipe a drive** (remove the first mibibyte and that way prepare it, so that most tools will be able to manage it, for example **gparted**),

but also

- **restore a drive to a standard storage device** (for example a USB pendrive) with an MSDOS partition table and a FAT32 file system. This is a quick and convenient 'standard method'.

There are also other features of mkusb, the main feature is to

- **create USB boot drives**.

See the following links

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe)

If you run standard Ubuntu *live*, you need an extra instruction to get the repository Universe. (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu have the repository Universe activated automatically.)

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only for standard Ubuntu # 14.04 and newer
sudo add-apt-repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ universe'  # 12.04

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
```