# What is mintstick.py and how to install it?

Tags: linux-mint, usb, live-usb, iso, disk-image

In Linux Mint, unlike in Ubuntu, I see two separate launchers to handle USB sticks, one only for formatting, the other for writing image files to the USB stick.

[image]

In the task manager I see in fact that they are both running `mintstick.py` with supplementary parameters for handling the iso.

[image]

Is this related to `usb-creator-gtk` (Startup Disk Creator) from Ubuntu?

Can it be used in other Linux systems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's Mint's alternative to usb creator. It is a graphical application to write .img and .iso files to USB keys. It can also format USB Key from a contextual menu in Cinammon and KDE desktops. It can be used in other linux systems, at least in Ubuntu for sure.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tsvetko.tsvetkov/trusty-backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mintstick
```

### UPDATE: that ppa is not updated and will not work in latest Ubuntu 18.04

For Ubuntu 18.04, until a newer version is launched along with a Ubuntu 18.04-based Linux Mint, download latest version 1.3.8 from [here](http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/main/m/mintstick/).

Open a terminal at the location of the download and do

```
sudo dpkg -i mintstick_1.3.8_all.deb
```

Install the missing dependencies.

If needed do

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

then do again  `sudo dpkg -i mintstick_1.3.8_all.deb`.

Actually mintstick is an improved version of USB-ImageWriter, which is based on dd utility and came from OpenSUSE and can work with any distro image. But Startup Disk Creator (usb-creator) is made for ubuntu and ubuntu-based systems only. It also has optional persistence option (all changes made to the system are saved, unlike a Live CD) which minstick doesn't have.

Installing `mintstick`, you will then have both the Image Writer and the USB Formatter.

[image]

Comment: what program is that exactly and is it different from the Ubuntu default one, or just a different GUI of the same program? and how to install it?

Comment: it's different. You can find sources to compile [on github](https://github.com/linuxmint/mintstick) or if you're using ubuntu you can add mint repo: `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ olivia main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install linuxmint-keyring`

`sudo apt-get install mintstick`

Comment: I have found more about what it is in fact [here](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-mintstick-1-2-1-on-ubuntu-14-04-pinguy-os-14-04-deepin-2014-lxle-14-04-and-other-ubuntu-14-04-derivatives/) and can be installed from a separate PPA as indicated there. It's the DD Tool. - The Ubuntu one is different then. What is it then? Elaborate a bit your answer is far too short.

Comment: Actually mintstick is an improved version of USB-ImageWriter, which is based on dd utility and came from OpenSUSE and can work with any distro image. But Startup Disk Creator (usb-creator) is made for ubuntu and ubuntu-based systems only. It also has optional persistence option (all changes made to the system are saved, unlike a Live CD) which minstick doesn't have.

Comment: added what you said and what i found into your answer to set it definitive, hope the edit is accepted

Comment: I cannot find a mintstick package in relation to opensuse lately. But I have added a method that works in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: this tool can also format to exFAT, which is greatly suited when it comes to USB sticks (namely with regard to speed and cross-platform access): https://askubuntu.com/a/1214554/925128